# layer.cornerRadius not working on tableView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

my tableView Cell is configured to have cornerRadius and it previously worked but now it just stopped working and its just straight without any cornerRadius

```
    func configure() {
    
    let firstCCR = CGFloat(10)
    cellContentViewMonitorimi.layer.cornerRadius = firstCCR
    trackImageView.layer.cornerRadius = firstCCR
    trackImageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    
    
    let secondCCR = CGFloat(5)
    colorsImageView.layer.cornerRadius = secondCCR 
    
}
```

And this is the warning that's showing on CLI:

2021-11-22 14:33:27.287685+0100 OnTra2[4132:160284] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000317efd0 UILabel:0x7fc1db0338f0.height == 15   (active)>

Comment: Post the entire cell.

Comment: Since you said it was working, maybe you could pinpoint what changed? iOS 15? Something else? Also, a warning is just that - a warning. From what you've posted it looks like you cell height is - somewhere - defined to be 15, and somewhere else defined to be something else. (Personally, I have to wonder what worked in the first place. Not trying to be mean, just wondering what supposedly changed.)

Comment: Fixed the issue, it was at the tableView cell configuration :)